# SparkSQL JDBC (PySpark) to Postgres - Creating Tables and Using CTEs

Tags: python, postgresql, apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark

I am working on a project to port a Python proof of concept (POC) over to PySpark. The POC heavily leverages Postgres and specifically the PostGIS geospatial library. Most the work consists of Python issuing commands to Postgres before calling back the data for final processing.

Some of the queries being passed to Postgres contain `CREATE TABLE`, `INSERT`, `CREATE TEMP TABLE`, and CTE `WITH` statements. I am trying to determine if it is possible to pass these queries to Postgres from Spark via JDBC.

Can someone confirm whether this functionality is available within Spark JDBC to other databases? To be clear, I am wanting to pass plain english SQL queries to Postgres, not use the SparkSQL APIs available (as they don't support all the operations I need). I am using **Spark version 2.3.0**, **PostgreSQL 10.11**, and **Python 2.7.5** (yes I know about EOL for Python 2, that's another story).

Here is what I've tried so far:

## Using `SparkSession.read`

### create Spark session to Postgres

```
postgres = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("myApp") \
    .config("spark.jars", "/usr/share/java/postgresql-jdbc.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

### define query to be passed to `dbtable` param

```
qry = """create table test (name varchar(50), age int)"""
```

### pass `qry`  to `dbtable` param of Postgres spark session object

```
postgres.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://....) \
    .option("dbtable", qry) \
    .option("user", configs['user']) \
    .option("password", configs['password']) \
    .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
    .option("ssl", "true") \
    .load()
```

Which returns the following syntax error (that same sort of error results when using other SQL commands listed above):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-5711943099029736374.py", line 367, in <module>
    raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-5711943099029736374.py", line 360, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in <module>
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 172, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load())
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o484.load.
: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "create"
  Position: 15
```

## Using `SparkSession.sql()`

### leverage same `postgres` object defined above

### pass query to .sql()

```
postgres.sql("""create table (name varchar(50), age int)""")
```

Which returns the following parse exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-5711943099029736374.py", line 367, in <module>
    raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-5711943099029736374.py", line 360, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 714, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 73, in deco
    raise ParseException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
ParseException: u"\nno viable alternative at input 'create table ('(line 1, pos 13)\n\n== SQL ==\ncreate table (name varchar(50), age int)\n-------------^^^\n"
```

And if I wrap the query in quotes as in `postgres.sql("(create table (name varchar(50), age int))")` I then get a different parse exception that leads me to believe the functionality I want is not possible:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-5711943099029736374.py", line 367, in <module>
    raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-5711943099029736374.py", line 360, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 714, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 73, in deco
    raise ParseException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
ParseException: u"\nextraneous input 'create' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'VALUES', 'TABLE', 'INSERT', 'MAP', 'REDUCE'}(line 1, pos 1)\n\n== SQL ==\n(create table (name varchar(50), age int))\n-^^^\n"
```

My questions boil down to:

1. Is my approach missing some sort of config or other necessary step?
2. Can the `spark.sql()` API be leveraged somehow with Postgres?
3. Is what I'm trying to accomplish even possible?

I have scoured the internet in attempts to find examples of using SparkSQL to issue these sorts of SQL queries to PostgreSQL but have not found any solutions. If there is a solution I would appreciate seeing an example, otherwise confirmation that this is not possible will be more than sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is what I'm trying to accomplish even possible?

I would say no. Spark is a framework for data processing therefore its API mostly developed for *read* and *write* operations with datasources. In your case, you have some DDL statements and Spark isn't supposed to perform such operations.

For example, `dbtable` option from your first example has to be a table name or some SELECT query.

If you need to run some DDL, DCL, TCL queries then you should do this other way, e.g. via `psycopg2` module.

> Can the spark.sql() API be leveraged somehow with Postgres?

`spark.sql` is a method to perform SparkSQL code over registered within SparkSession tables or views. It works with any supported datasources, not only jdbc, but it works on a Spark side with SparkSQL syntax. For example

```
val spark = SparkSession
        ...
        .getOrCreate()

spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://ip/database_name")
  .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename")
  .load()
  .createOrReplaceTempView("my_spark_table_over_postgresql_table")

// and then you can operate with a view:
val df = spark.sql("select * from my_spark_table_over_postgresql_table where ... ")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that was my guy feeling but I wanted some confirmation and you provided just that! And thanks for the clarification re SparkSession tables.

As for your comment on `psycopg2`, I've used it before in non-distributed applications and hadn't considered giving it a try within a Spark application. Do you have experience with this / could speak to its efficacy? If you have any links I could reference on this integration I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Not the best option but you can solve it using SQL injection.

```
spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", s"""jdbc:postgresql://8.8.8.8/dbname""")
  .option(
    "dbtable",
    "(select 1) a; CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW schema.view AS SELECT c1 FROM schema.table WHERE c1 in ('C', 'H'); select * from (select 1) a"
  )
  .load()
```

Spark returns an error but the view is getting created:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Multiple ResultSets were returned by the query.

My solution is valid for Spark 2.3.0, in Spark 3.2.0 there is better option than hacking "dbtable", you can use field called "query".

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60103327/3072095) is great and explains the situation well. Another way to think about is that Spark is a data processing framework and deals with lazy execution. Everything is transformation or action. To materialize we need to perform actions. Now keeping this in mind, can you perform the DDL task at hand? Even if there was some hack, but does that come naturally to Spark framework? Also hacks might cause unexpected behaviours, we should be mindful of that.

To summarize DDL statements (CREATE, ALTER, DROP, GRANT, REVOKE, etc) are not possible from spark.